# How to use RabinMillerTest() in CryptoPP?

Tags: c++, crypto++

Can anyone share an example of RabinMillerTest() that works?  My googlefu is sadly lacking.

Here is my test code:

```
#include "integer.h"
#include "nbtheory.h"
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator rng;
    CryptoPP::Integer a("123456789");
    CryptoPP::Integer b;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is prime: " << IsPrime(a) << std::endl;
    b=a+CryptoPP::Integer::Two();
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is prime: " << IsPrime(b) << std::endl;
    int r=RabinMillerTest(rng,&b,2);
    std::cout << "RabinMiller: " << r <<std::endl;
}
```

Here is the build command:

```
g++ bignum.cpp -I.  -fpermissive libcryptopp.a
```

The only example I could find is here:

http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Diffie-Hellman

My code crashes every time I run it, and one crash was so bad I had to cold boot to recover.  If I remove the call to RabinMillerTest() then it runs fine.  I suspect a problem with C++ syntax is the culprit, but I just don't see it.  Since I can't use it properly, I am currently stripping the guts of the RabinMillerTest() function to use separately.

Comment: Looking at how it is used in the example you linked, `&b` seems incorrect, it should just be `b`.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that.  I tried a lot of things.  The function declaration requires &b, so that is mostly what I tried.  Finally I started ripping apart the RabinMillerTest() function, moving more and more pieces into an in-line version so the function call with the &b notation would not get in the way.  I got that to work!  The problem really is in the documentation.  They insist you pass a Class RandomNumberGenerator & to the function, but that is not true.  You must pass a class that is derived from RandomNumberGenerator, and then it works as advertized.

Comment: It sounds like you may be confused by the `&` in the function declaration.  That means the parameter is taken by reference.  By passing `&b` you are passing the address of `b` which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong signature for `MillerRabinTest`. Here's what it is (from `nbtheory.h`):

```
CRYPTOPP_DLL bool CRYPTOPP_API RabinMillerTest(RandomNumberGenerator &rng,
                                   const Integer &w, unsigned int rounds);
```

Instead of:

```
int r=RabinMillerTest(rng,&b,2);
```

Try:

```
bool b=RabinMillerTest(rng, b, 2);
```

There's also a discussion of Miller-Rabin round counts on the Cryptography Stack Exchange at [Trial divisions before Miller-Rabin checks?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17707/trial-divisions-before-miller-rabin-checks). It was written with OpenSSL and Crypto++ in mind.

Comment: I tried changing to: bool r=RabinMillerTest(rng,b,2); and it still crashes.  I will paste my final solution into the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer edited into the question. Adding as a separate answer block. Credit goes to user3920315.

---

UPDATE:  I got it to work.  Here is the working code:

```
#include "integer.h"
#include "nbtheory.h"
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    //CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator rng;
    CryptoPP::NonblockingRng rng;
    CryptoPP::Integer a("123456789");
    CryptoPP::Integer b;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is prime: " << IsPrime(a) << std::endl;
    b=a+CryptoPP::Integer::Two();
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is prime: " << IsPrime(b) << std::endl;
    bool r=RabinMillerTest(rng,b,2);
    std::cout << "RabinMiller: " << r <<std::endl;
}
```

I changed the call to `RabinMillerTest()` but the resulting executable would still crash.

When I changed the random number generator to a class that inherits from `RandomNumberGenerator`, then it works.